# Any one can fix the command , I try the command but CMD Command get error ,

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command

I try to  rut this command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /r C:\Users\sam\Desktop %f in (*.*) do @copy "%f" E:\testresult/exclude:E:\testresult\except.TXT
```

but I get error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect
> the excetp.txt contains 2 line (*.html , *.jpg)

any one can help me

Comment: the excetp.txt contains 2 line (*.html , *.jpg)

Comment: the excetp.txt contains 2 line (*.html , *.jpg) this line not including error

Comment: The first suggestion I'd make is that you change `copy` to `xcopy` example:`For /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop" %G In (*) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%G" "E:\testresult" /Exclude:"E:\testresult\except.txt" /Y /C /I /R /K`. Alternatively, use `copy`, but exclude using `findstr`, example: `For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop" /B /A:-D-S-H 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /L /I /E /G:"E:\testresult\except.txt"') Do Copy /Y "%G" "E:\testresult"`, and change `E:\testresult\except.TXT` to remove the leading asterisks.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the recursion in my last example: `For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir "%UserProfile%\Desktop" /B /S /A:-D-S-H 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /V /L /I /E /G:"E:\testresult\except.txt"') Do Copy /Y "%G" "E:\testresult"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making several mistakes and the easiest way to see that is to NOT use @ until it works.

we could run your command without @ to see what might be wrong with your copy command

```
for /R %userprofile%\Desktop %f in (*.*) do copy "%f" E:\testresult/exclude:E:\testresult\except.TXT
```

You would see lots of **`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`**
So it looks like the first part is working. Let us now replace @copy with echo copy to get a better look at the output

```
for /R %userprofile%\Desktop %f in (*.*) do echo copy "%f" E:\testresult/exclude:E:\testresult\except.TXT
```

and after all the files the last one might be

```
copy "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\Everything.html" E:\testresult/exclude:E:\testresult\except.TXT
```

SO what is wrong at this point ?

**Hint** the end bit has more than one : because there is no space before /exclude
AND AFAIK there is no copy /exclude option run **Xcopy /?**

**Later edit** @Compo in comment above shows you better methods